# Error: Unexpected end of multipart data] storageErrors: [] in express.js-iOS (Objective-C) app

Tags: ios, objective-c, node.js, express, multer

I've tried to find solution of this problem, couldn't find anything in node.js/express.js and iOS app. My client has requirements not to use any third party libraries. So, I am not using AFNetworking. Any help or if someone can just tell why the error is coming would be greatly appreciated.

I am trying to send multipart form data, image with text. Whenever i do POST i get error as: Unexpected end of multipart data.

Code for POST in iOS:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://172.16.0.5:8080/upload"];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

    NSString *boundary = @"YOUR_BOUNDARY_STRING";
    NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@", boundary];
    [request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

    NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];

    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"photo\"; filename=\"%@.jpg\"\r\n", self.path] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:self.imageData]];

    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"message\"\r\n\r\n%@", self.mealTitleTextField.text] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"user\"\r\n\r\n%d", 1] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    [request setHTTPBody:body];

    NSURLResponse *response;
    NSError *error;

    [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];
```

This is how I am getting image file path:

```
 NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,
                                                         NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    self.path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:
                      @"test.png" ];
    self.imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
    [self.imageData writeToFile:self.path atomically:YES];
```

Here is the server code:

```
router.post('/upload', function(req,res,next){
    upload.single('photo')(req, res, function(err){
        if (err) {
            console.log(err)
            res.send(err);
            return;
        }

        console.log(req.file);
        res.json({'ok':'ok'});
    });
});``
```

Answer (score 0):

You should verify the format of the uploaded form data - there may be some missing LINE_END or LINE_START, see [cordova-plugin-file-transfer Android implementation](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file-transfer/blob/007f98692b15f5a6c4902abf393bee8dc5edeced/src/android/FileTransfer.java#L389-L411) as a reference.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I installed `https bypass` app. 
When I turned off the application, the error disappeared.